# Redundant equations in the definition of jointly independent events

Tags: probability, independence

The events $A_1, A_2, \ldots A_n$ are said to be ***jointly independent*** if for every $2 \leq k \leq n$ and $1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \ldots < i_k \leq n$ we have

$$ P(A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2} \cap \ldots \cap A_{i_k}) = P(A_{i_1}) P(A_{i_2}) \ldots P(A_{i_k}). $$

A set of jointly independent events are always pairwise independent, but for $n \geq 3$ the converse is false, which means the equations for $k=2$ only do not necessarily imply joint independence.

In this sense it is natural to ask the following question: What is the minimum number of equations of the type

$$ P(A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2} \cap \ldots \cap A_{i_k}) = P(A_{i_1}) P(A_{i_2}) \ldots P(A_{i_k}) $$

which already give a sufficient condition for joint independence? I.e. how many redundant equations are there in the definition of jointly independent events?

Comment: The usual construction for "pairwise independence does not imply joint dependence" has a slight modification showing $n$ events, every subset of $n-1$ of which is jointly independent, but not all $n$.  This satisfies $2^n-n$ of your equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim:** The answer is $0$. We can't get rid of any equations.

**Lemma**: for every $n$ there are $n+1$ events, which are not jointly independent, but any $n$  items of them are independent.

**Proof of lemma:** let $\xi_{i}$ be independent $Bern(\frac12)$ r.v., $1 \le i \le n$. Put $\xi_{n+1} = I_{\sum_{i=1}^n \xi_i \text{ is odd}}$. Finally, put $A_i = I_{\xi_i = 1}$.

**Proof of claim:** it's sufficient to prove that for any $j_1 < j_2 < \ldots < j_m$ there are $A_1$, $A_2, \ldots, A_n$ such that $$ P(A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2} \cap \ldots \cap A_{i_k}) = P(A_{i_1}) P(A_{i_2}) \ldots P(A_{i_k})$$
for any $\{i_1, \ldots, i_k\}$ except $\{j_1, j_2, ..., j_m\}$.

Take $A_{j_1}, A_{j_2}, \ldots, A_{j_m}$ from lemma and put $A_i = \varnothing$ for all $i \notin \{j_1, j_2, ..., j_m\}$. Thus if $i_{\alpha} \in  \{j_1, j_2, ..., j_m\}$ we have $$ P(A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2} \cap \ldots \cap A_{i_k}) =  0= P(A_{i_1}) P(A_{i_2}) \ldots P(A_{i_k}).$$

If $\{i_1, i_2, ..., i_k\} \subset \{j_1, j_2, ..., j_m\}$ and $k < m$ then it follows from lemma that $$ P(A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2} \cap \ldots \cap A_{i_k}) =  P(A_{i_1}) P(A_{i_2}) \ldots P(A_{i_k}).$$

Q.e.d.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation.

Comment: @d_sandor, you are welcome!